# Regular expression to find a word at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string, based on the end character of that string I need to check a condition. I have managed to write following script, but its not taking as I intended.

```
//var receivers_type = "d2845a48f91b29f9d0a6e96858f05d85xing";
var receivers_type = "d21fca8635940e97d0f8e132d806cedaxingpage";
if (/.*xing/.test(receivers_type)) {
    console.log('xing profile');
    flag = 1;
}
if (/.*xingpage/.test(receivers_type)) {
    console.log('xing page');
    flag = 0;
}
```

when `receivers_type = "d2845a48f91b29f9d0a6e96858f05d85xing"` condition is working properly. it will only enter into first if loop. But when the `receivers_type = "d21fca8635940e97d0f8e132d806cedaxingpage"` it is entering in to both if cases. Could you help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `.*` selector, so you should use the folowing regexp

```
/xing$/  <-- the character $ means that the xing must be at the end of the string
```

So your code will be:

```
//var receivers_type = "d2845a48f91b29f9d0a6e96858f05d85xing";
var receivers_type = "d21fca8635940e97d0f8e132d806cedaxingpage";
if (/xing$/.test(receivers_type)) {
    console.log('xing profile');
    flag = 1;
}
if (/xingpage$/.test(receivers_type)) {
    console.log('xing page');
    flag = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the end of the string in your regex.

You can do this using the "end of string anchor", which is a dollar character.

```
var receivers_type = "d21fca8635940e97d0f8e132d806cedaxingpage";
if (/.*xing$/.test(receivers_type)) {
  console.log('xing profile');
}
if (/.*xingpage$/.test(receivers_type)) {
  console.log('xing page');
}
```

You can read more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use following expression:

```
/xingpage$/
```

So you would have:

```
if (/xingpage$/.test(receivers_type)) {
    console.log('xing page');
    flag = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use match in Javascript and change the regex:

`if(recievers_type.match(/(xingpage)$/)`